# Order a Symfony2 collection

Tags: symfony, sorting

I have an `\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection` of objects

Without doing a foreach loop and putting it into an array, then doing a usort - is there any way I can order that collection by each objects `$obj->getName()` ascending?

Comment: How do you get your collection of objects? if its a query you can already sort it

Comment: A Collection is not sortable, but you can get an iterator and apply on it a sort and generate a new collection with the result. Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

Use Doctrine built-in annotation for that purpose

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AnEntity", mappedBy="someVar")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"aField" = "ASC"})
 *
 * @var ArrayCollection
 */
private $aCollection;
```

API Reference: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-orderby

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way.

But if you retrieve your collection from DB you can request data with `ORDER BY` statement and you will have the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I see 3 possible ways of doing this. And which one you choose depends on how you retrieve the data, and what kind of behavior you want out of it.

**You build a sql-query to retrieve the entities**

In this case you would use an `ORDER BY` statement for your query.

**The entities you're retrieving have a relation to another entity and should always be sorted this way**

This is what ihsan answered already:

> Use Doctrine built-in annotation for that purpose
>
> `/**
>    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AnEntity", mappedBy="someVar")
>    * @ORM\OrderBy({"aField" = "ASC"})
>    *
>    * @var ArrayCollection
>    */
>   private $aCollection;`
>
> API Reference: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-orderby

**You just have a collection, and/or want to sort it in a specific way**

For this case you can use Criteria's. According to the documentation, it might either sort it with SQL or PHP depending on the fact if the collection is still in the DB, or in-memory. This is some mechanism with lazy-loading. Don't ask the details.

```
$criteria = Criteria::create();
$criteria->orderBy(array('column' => 'ASC'));

$sortedItems = $items->matching($criteria);
```

You can read more on Criteria's here:
http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections